# Pivoting tables in MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have some data that I want to pivot.

```
---------------------------------------------
| date         | price  | col_1 | col_2    |
---------------------------------------------
| 2017-12-10   | 26     | fruit | apple    |
| 2017-12-10   | 346    | Vege  | carrot   |
| 2017-12-11   | 644    | Sweet | cake     |
| 2017-12-11   | 35435  | fruit | banana   |
| 2017-12-12   | 453455 | veggie| beans    |
---------------------------------------------
```

col_1 and col_2 are combinations of categories 
So basically the output should be 1 row per unique date, and the rest of the columns should be relevant combinations of col_1 and col2 separated by a hyphen. The table will be populated by the total price of the combination of col_1 col_2 item per date. the diagram below might be useful:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| date         | fruit - apple|  fruit - banana| val n-SubVal n    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-12-10   | NULL         | 56             |    and so on
| 2017-12-11   | 100          | NULL           |
| 2017-12-12   | NULL         | 900            |
| 2017-12-13   | 45           | NULL           |
| 2017-12-14   | NULL         | NULL           |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

after about 4 hours talking to a friend and research we have come up with this script below. It executes but nothing gets returned except a very odd error.

```
Incorrect syntax near '*some value in either col_1 or col_2*'.
```

the error is supposedly happening either at the first or second declare statement (whichever line MSSQL randomly chooses as its never the same line #).

Any help in getting the above output will be appreciated. 
Thank you very much.

```
declare @dynamicpivotquery as NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @columnname as NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @columnname = COALESCE(@columnname + ', ','') + quotename(col_1) + quotename(col_1)
from (select distinct col_1, col_2 from *tablename*) as d

set @dynamicpivotquery = 
N'select distinct date, ' + @columnname + ' from *tablename*
PIVOT (sum(price) for d in (' + @columnname + ')) as pivot12'

EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicpivotquery
```

Comment: Where is that text `'*some value in either col_1 or col_2*` added to your dynamic query? You are mixing up the column names `col_1` and `col_2` with `cat_1` and `cat_2`. Where do you add the conactenated field to the source data (with a column name of `d`)?

Comment: my bad - unfortunately I asked my question without checking the code I pasted and then it wouldn't let me edit. the *some value* part is the error I receive where *xx* is any random value from my data such as apple, banana, alcohol etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query :

```
    declare @dynamicpivotquery as NVARCHAR(MAX)
    declare @columnname as NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @columnname = COALESCE(@columnname + ', ','') + QuoteName(cat)
    from (select distinct cat_1+'-'+cat_2 as cat from #YourTable) as d

    SET @dynamicpivotquery = 
    N';WITH p AS (
        SELECT sold_date,  [cat_1] +''-'' +[cat_2]  AS CATCOL, SUM(sold_price) AS sold_price  
        FROM #YourTable
        GROUP BY sold_date, [cat_1] + ''-'' + [cat_2]
        )
        SELECT sold_date,  ' + @columnname + '
        FROM p
        PIVOT (SUM([sold_price]) FOR CATCOL IN (' + @columnname + ')) AS pivotcat12'

    EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicpivotquery
```

Sample data :

```
    sold_date   sold_price  cat_1   cat_2   cat_12
    ----------------------------------------------------
    2017-12-10  26,00       fruit   apple   fruit-apple
    2017-12-10  346,00      vege    carrot  vege-carrot
    2017-12-11  644,00      sweet   cake    sweet-cake
    2017-12-11  35435,00    fruit   banana  fruit-banana
    2017-12-12  453455,00   veggie  beans   veggie-beans
    2017-12-12  100,00      other   fruits  other-fruits
    2017-12-12  100,00      other   fruits  other-fruits
    2017-12-12  100,00      other   fruits  other-fruits
```

Dynamic query string :

```
    ;WITH p AS (
        SELECT sold_date,  [cat_1] +'-' +[cat_2]  AS CATCOL, SUM(sold_price) AS sold_price  
        FROM #YourTable
        GROUP BY sold_date, [cat_1] + '-' + [cat_2]
        )
        SELECT sold_date,  [fruit-apple], [fruit-banana], [other-fruits], [sweet-cake], [vege-carrot], [veggie-beans]
        FROM p
        PIVOT (
        SUM([sold_price])
        FOR CATCOL IN ([fruit-apple], [fruit-banana], [other-fruits], [sweet-cake], [vege-carrot], [veggie-beans])) AS pivotcat12
```

Result :

```
    sold_date   fruit-apple fruit-banana    other-fruits    sweet-cake  vege-carrot veggie-beans
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2017-12-10  26,00       NULL            NULL            NULL        346,00      NULL
    2017-12-11  NULL        35435,00        NULL            644,00      NULL        NULL
    2017-12-12  NULL        NULL            300,00          NULL        NULL        453455,00
```

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks on your query:

- The sample data has fieldnames `date`, `price`, `col_1` and `col_2` while your query uses fieldnames of `sold_date`, `sold_price`, `cat_1` and `cat_2`.
- You could have had a look at the result in the variable `@dynamicpivotquery` to see what's wrong: `[fruit][apple]` is not a valid fieldname. It should have been `[fruit - apple]` instead.
- The PIVOT query did not know the field `d` with the concatenated category names.
- The `distinct` in the dynamic query isn't needed. You have to make sure that only the required fields (`sold_date`, `sold_price` and `d`) are contained in the source for the PICOT command, because otherwise query will also be grouped by all additional fields, which will result in unwanted rows.

Your code could work like this:

```
DECLARE @dynamicpivotquery nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @columnnames nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @columnnames = 
  ISNULL(@columnnames + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(ISNULL(cat_1, '') + ' - ' + ISNULL(cat_2, ''))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cat_1, cat_2 FROM tablename) AS d

SET @dynamicpivotquery = 
N'SELECT sold_date, ' + @columnnames + N'
FROM 
  (SELECT sold_date, sold_price, 
     ISNULL(cat_1, '''') + '' - '' + ISNULL(cat_2, '''') AS d 
   FROM tablename
  ) AS src
PIVOT (SUM(sold_price) FOR d IN (' + @columnnames + ')) AS pivot12'

EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicpivotquery
```

Comment: I have to say that your code is shorter and simpler than mine..both produce the same results...

Comment: Indeed your code is nearly the same, except that you use `GROUP BY` in your cte which isn't needed, because `PIVOT` does this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot The data Twice. Just apply the same logic dynamically so that it appears for all combinations of col_1 and col_2.

```
select * from
( select [DATE], [col_1] ,[col_2],[price]
from *tablename*
) TableName
pivot
(sum(price)
for col_1 in (fruit)
) as FirstPivot
pivot
(sum(fruit)
for col_2 in (apple,banana)
) as SecondPivot
```